# API is using CORS, how can I use axios in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I need to do a GET request from a CORS enabled corona virus API with axios and Vue, and I have no control over their server. My Vue app was created with vue-cli.

Actually I do two requests from different API's, one works without CORS the other with the exact same code, but on a second component complains just because the server enforces CORS

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://corona-api.com/countries' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

What can I do?

Comment: Proxy the calls through your server. Ask the API provider to permit CORS. Find another API.

Comment: @ceejayoz I think I would like to try the proxy solution. Can you provide a url?

Comment: Link to what? He meant using your own webserver as proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is that http is being redireced to https, you get a redirect header, which is absent of wildcard CORS policy.

as you can see, 
https://codesandbox.io/s/javascript-es6-axios-app-y80n5

this works fine for axios request to 'https://corona-api.com/countries'